# Can't start X on fresh install

Tags: debian, xorg, nouveau, optimus

I started X successfully just once. After reboot, I'm stuck on this screen
[image]

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x8) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPSS I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev ff)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

`~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`

```
[    17.163] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[    17.163] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    17.163] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[    17.163] Current Operating System: Linux 230-pacholdeb 4.3.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.5-1 (2016-02-06) x86_64
[    17.163] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.3.0-1-amd64 root=UUID=84be8ee7-09ac-4fe4-a2aa-c512d328fcee ro quiet
[    17.163] Build Date: 20 July 2016  05:14:41AM
[    17.163] xorg-server 2:1.18.4-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[    17.163] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    17.163]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    17.163] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    17.164] (==) Log file: "/home/pacholik/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Aug  8 14:37:54 2016
[    17.167] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    17.169] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    17.169] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    17.169] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    17.169] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    17.170] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    17.170] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    17.170] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    17.170] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    17.170] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    17.171] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    17.171]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    17.175] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    17.175] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    17.175] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    17.175] (II) Loader magic: 0x55fccd175dc0
[    17.175] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    17.175]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    17.175]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    17.175]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    17.175]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    17.177] (++) using VT number 1

[    17.181] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[    17.182] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    42.188] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to take device /dev/dri/card1: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

I'd like X to get going using OSS drivers or just Intel graphics.

---

EDIT Aug 11:

It looks like one in maybe twenty boots is successful. I'm in X now, but I do not dare to reboot.

---

EDIT Aug 15:

Ok, I managed to run X on Intel GPU - by uninstalling *bumblebee* and adding `nouveau.modeset=0` to kernel parameters. But I still don't know how to use the NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: Don't bumblebee require nvidia proprietary drivers? Uninstall nouveau, install nvidia drivers.

Comment: According to wiki it doesn't https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem building A Debian Devuan fork from scratch. I suspect it's the mismatch between the build environment linux-image 4.9 for the xorg server as opposed to the Linux kernel version you're booting. Not sure if that helps or not. But ill post my findings once I also solve this problem...